# How is this fat arrow operating in this code?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at this code here and wondering how the arrow function is working here. Is it related to the concept of the lexical this?

```
function multiplier(factor) {
  return number => number * factor;
 }

 const multiplier = (factor) => {
   return number => number * factor;
};

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

For example, I can refactor this like so:

```
const multiplier = (factor) => number => number * factor;

let twice = multiplier(2);
console.log(twice(5));
```

And it still works. So am I in the ballpark of how the fat arrow is being used here?

Comment: that is just a closure.

Comment: Right, just a closure, and `this` has nothing to do with it; it's not mentioned at all in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function multiplier(factor) {
    return number => number * factor;
}
```

is simply equivalent to

```
function multiplier(factor) {
    return function(number) { return number * factor };
}
```

There's no `this` involved here.